# If we will remove public url from path then why laravel community added it in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Usually when we download  fresh laravel setup from laravel website for execute it usually we locate public floder.
but later on we will delete public from url. than why they have added in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you get it wrongly.

Laravel `public` folder serves the content of your website. the entire framework and vendor directory are behind this path. so public users cannot access all those folders its primary security for the framework.

It means on server you don't upload the entire framework to `public_html` folder and don't point the domain to `public` folder of laravel without setting proper symlink.

This point can be done with symlink creation in servers. for example you can edit the host file in Linux/Windows and set the project domain. something like `homested.app`.
Then in your apache configuration simply set this project domain to its physical path.
like below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName homestead.app
DocumentRoot /home/User/Development/homestead/public
<Directory />
Require all granted
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So you can access the project in browser like `homestead.app` for more details check this [link](http://www.walkswithme.net/laravel-setup-in-linux-machine).

Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer to this (I presume) is organization and security.

When all the public WWW-access files are kept inside the `public` directory, you can point your virtual host directly to that folder. This means that the application level files (`.env`, `config`, `app` and so on) are *not* publicly accessible to web browsers. This in turn means that no one can use a web browser to accidentally or on purpose browse your source code or configuration.